# FULLTEXT key too long

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I get the following error when trying to add a FULLTEXT index to Title, Edition and Author in my MySQL database:

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Here are the columns:

```
`Title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Edition` varchar(20) default NULL,
`Authors` varchar(255) default NULL,
```

None of them are unique.. Even the combination of all 3 is not unique.  Primary key on the database is the ISBN.

The reason I'm adding this FULLTEXT index is so people can search for books using a keyword that might include the Title, the Edition, or the Author.

Comment: The answer to this question was already given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes/3489331#3489331).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a limit on how much space is allocated for indexes - [it's 1000 bytes for MyISAM, 767 for InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

The only way around the limitation is to define keys that index a portion of the column - which means that's all that will be in the index, limiting it's value:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON YOUR_TABLE(title(100), edition, authors(100));
```

That will index the first 100 characters of the title column, all of the edition column, and 100 characters of the authors column.  I believe is a 3 to 1 ratio for VARCHAR columns, so VARCHAR(250) takes 750 bytes.