# How do I increase key length in MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql

When running a Rails migration that creates an index, I get:

```
Mysql::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_matches_on_foo_and_bar_id_and_baz_id` ON `matches` (`foo`, `bar_id`, `baz_id`)
```

What MySQL variable do I need to set to increase this, and where do I set it so it affects all sessions, and not just the current client session?

Comment: Can you reduce the size of foo? It'll help while taking into account the 2 answers below.

Comment: An interesting question would be why you need to index a field of that size...

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I'm building a database from a blank schema for a production Rails app on my development environment, so no changes allowed (except to the migration that is causing the problem, of course).

Comment: The answer to this question was already given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes/3489331#3489331) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes/1814594#1814594).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

InnoDB actually only allows 768 BYTES in the index. Also, note that UTF-8 encoded strings take up 3 bytes per character, so you only have 768 / 3 chars to play with in the index in that case.

A possible solution is to limit the length of the field use in the index. However, since you also want a unique index, that might not be an acceptable solution for you. Use the following to limit the length of the fields used.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_matches_on_foo_and_bar_id_and_baz_id` ON `matches` (`foo`(100), `bar_id`(100), `baz_id`(100))
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html):

> "The maximum key length is 1000 bytes.
>   This can also be changed by changing
>   the source and recompiling"

Comment: Hrm, that's annoying. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: that sucks, why can't it be a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the collation from one option to another that supports the key length needed. I personnally had to chnage from server default to latin 1 - default.