# How do I limit field lengths when creating an index in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a migration that adds an index to an existing table using [`add_index`](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.1.2/doc/index.html?a=M001540&name=add_index):

```
add_index :foo, [:foo_type, :bar_id, :baz_id], :unique => true
```

However, my fields are long enough that they exceed the maximum InnoDB key length. As per [Anders Arpteg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898518/how-do-i-increase-key-length-in-mysql-5-1/5898665#5898665) to [How do I increase key length in MySQL 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898518/how-do-i-increase-key-length-in-mysql-5-1), I need to generate SQL like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_matches_on_foo_and_bar_id_and_baz_id` ON `matches` (`foo`(100), `bar_id`(100), `baz_id`(100))
```

Can I do this in a nice Rails-y way, or must I stoop to using raw SQL in my migration?

Comment: Check this link :
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9855#issuecomment-28874587 Might sure be helpful, works very well on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, rails do not support the :limit option in add_index (at least not in 2.x). However, you can always use execute instead and enter the sql directly.

Comment: Rails 2.x **does** support the :length option.

Comment: Same link as my other comment -- my comment here meant that while it may not support the :limit option (which I don't see how that affects your problem, since the :limit option has to do with creating/altering fields/columns, not indexes), it does support the :length option. http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements#add_index-instance_method

Answer (score 10):

You can specify manual lengths for each field you use, to stay under the total limit:

```
add_index(:foo, [:foo_type, :bar_id, :baz_id], :unique => true, :length => {:foo_type => 100, :bar_id => 20, :baz_id => 20})
```

Comment: The length of the index's **name** is not the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with Rails 2.3.11; what version did you test it on?

Comment: I didn't test it (I don't have MySQL installed), but the Rails 2.3.8 docs show this as an example: `add_index(:accounts, [:name, :surname], :name => 'by_name_surname', :length => {:name => 10, :surname => 15})`

Comment: That's really odd--do you have a link to that documentation?

Comment: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements#add_index-instance_method

Answer (score 6):

You can specify length parameter, this will generate the exact SQL you asked for:

```
add_index :foo, [:foo_type, :bar_id, :baz_id], :unique => true, :length => 100
```

Two drawbacks:

1. The parameter gets used for all three keys so you can't specify different lengths for individual keys.
2. This functionality is added in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter, so you have to use MysqlAdapter for it to work (maybe other adapters implement it also, I just know Rails does not support it by itself).

Comment: Very nice! I think I can't (or shouldn't) switch adapters here, so I guess I'll go with Anders's `execute` solution, but I'm sure your solution will be appropriate for others in my boat. :)