# Flask-SQLAlchemy specified key too long

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following Flask-SQLAlchemy schema:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    username = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default="")

    email = db.Column(db.String(254), nullable=False, unique=True)
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    is_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_enabled
```

Which generates the SQL (I'm using MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    username VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, 
    confirmed_at DATETIME, 
    is_enabled BOOL NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (username), 
    UNIQUE (email), 
    CHECK (is_enabled IN (0, 1))
)
```

However, this gives me the error "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes".

Note that this is *not* a duplicate of [Can't create_all Flask-SQLAlchemy - specified key was too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411679/cant-create-all-flask-sqlalchemy-specified-key-was-too-long); that question suggested shortening unique column lengths to <255 characters, and I have tried that with no success.

I would like, if possible, to keep the email field at 254 characters as that is the max length as defined by the spec.

Comment: _"and I have tried that with no success."_ Please post what you have tried - it might be what we need to help

Comment: @DaniSpringer If you want specifics, I tried shortening both the password and email fields to 214.

Comment: What's your encoding? 254 characters of max 4 bytes per character (utf8mb4) would equate to 1016 bytes.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have no idea. Whatever the default MySQL encoding is, I suppose.