# InnoDB maximum key length

Tags: mysql, innodb

This is a fairly straight forward question but I'm having a problem finding a clear answer googling around. On MySQL 5.1.53, using InnoDB, and a varchar(1024) field (I'm indexing Exchange 2010 Event IDs). I'm wondering what the maximum key length is when I index this field. I'm wondering if I should shorten the field and use something like an sha512 hash if the key length isn't long enough.

Comment: The answer to this question was already given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes/3489331#3489331) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes/1814594#1814594).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The InnoDB internal maximum key length is 3500 bytes, but MySQL itself restricts this to 3072 bytes. This limit applies to the length of the combined index key in a multi-column index.

And, as noted:

An index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes. The same length limit applies to any index key prefix. See Section 12.1.13, “CREATE INDEX Syntax”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html