# max key length is 1000 bytes in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

when i am running jboss using mysqlworkbench in RHEL 6 .i am getting this error max key length is 1000 bytes .how to change the utf-8 charaterset to latin-1 in mysqlworkbench.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [documentation for MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html) you may specify the character set on database level (`create database DD default character set latin1`), table level (`create table TT (...) default character set latin1`) or column level (`FF varchar(50) character set latin1 not null`). This will allow you to use more characters in unique index, but cannot overcome [MySQL limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes/3489331#3489331).