# SQL: Key Specified Is Too Long

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I Tried To Install phpMyLibrary. During Step 3 Installer Gives Me An Error In SQL Commands. Error Is As Follows:

**`SQL=Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`**

My Codes Are:

```
CREATE TABLE `#__patron` (
  `uid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `gid` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `branch` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sup` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `org` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `add1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `add2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ethnic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `graddate` date NOT NULL,
  `parentinfo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custfield1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custfield2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custfield3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custfield4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `barcode` (`barcode`),
  KEY `name` (`name`,`code`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I Doesn't Know Which Key Specified Is Too Long Help To Me Fix This Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from referencing too many bytes in the `key`-- you've reached the 1000 byte limit for a key with `name`, `code` and `type`:

```
KEY `name` (`name`,`code`,`type`)
```

That key contains 3 varchar fields.  Each varchar field is equivalent to 3 times its precision.  This results in `3*(255+100+100) = 1365 bytes`

If you switch your engine from `myisam` to `innodb` it will work.  If that's not an option, you need to remove that `key` or reduce its size.

- [Working Fiddle (myisam) Without Key](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef773/1)
- [Working Fiddle (innodb) With Key](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f543/1)

Here's a good post about the limits with keys in mysql: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489331/1073631

Comment: You've nailed it, but just wanted to clarify that the 3x length is not always true, it depends on character encoding. UTF-8 is 3x length, but latin1 is 1x length, others vary.

Comment: @HartCO -- thanks for the clarification, very useful.