# Error; #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have tried importing directly from phpMyAdmin, and I keep getting error responses like this:

> Error
>
> SQL query:
>
> --
>   -- Indexes for table `configurations`
>   -- ALTER TABLE `configurations` ADD KEY `admin_password_2` ( `admin_password` , `admin_username` , `captcha` , `censored_words` ,
>   `chat` ) , ADD KEY `comment_character_limit_2` (
>   `comment_character_limit` , `email` , `email_verification` , `friends`
>   , `language` , `message_character_limit` ) , ADD KEY `reg_req_about_2`
>   ( `reg_req_about` , `reg_req_birthday` , `reg_req_currentcity` ,
>   `reg_req_hometown` , `site_name` , `site_title` , `smooth_links` ,
>   `story_character_limit` , `theme` ) ;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Check this table below

### Table structure for table `configurations`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `configurations` (
  `ad_place_hashtag` text NOT NULL,
  `ad_place_home` text NOT NULL,
  `ad_place_messages` text NOT NULL,
  `ad_place_search` text NOT NULL,
  `ad_place_timeline` text NOT NULL,
  `admin_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
  `admin_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xxxx',
  `captcha` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `censored_words` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'racist,retard',
  `chat` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_character_limit` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no-reply@website.com',
  `email_verification` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friends` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `language` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'english',
  `message_character_limit` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_req_about` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_req_birthday` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_req_currentcity` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reg_req_hometown` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reset_time` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `site_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Site Name',
  `site_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Site Title',
  `smooth_links` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `story_character_limit` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `theme` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `configurations`

```
INSERT INTO `configurations` (`ad_place_hashtag`, `ad_place_home`, `ad_place_messages`, `ad_place_search`, `ad_place_timeline`, `admin_password`, `admin_username`, `captcha`, `censored_words`, `chat`, `comment_character_limit`, `email`, `email_verification`, `friends`, `language`, `message_character_limit`, `reg_req_about`, `reg_req_birthday`, `reg_req_currentcity`, `reg_req_hometown`, `reset_time`, `site_name`, `site_title`, `smooth_links`, `story_character_limit`, `theme`) VALUES
('', '', '', '', '', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 1, 'racist,retard', 0, 0, 'no-reply@website.com', 0, 0, 'english', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Site Name', 'Site Title', 0, 0, 'lemon');
```

Can anyone assist me with this? I need to get around this obstacle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

there is an answer to this question at, would comment but no points yet hehe.

its solely a engine issues however he has a index partial solution

[Mysql::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)