# Typo3 Upgrade 7.6.31 to 8.7.19 / Database Analyzer fails

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

during the upgrade process from 7.6 to 8.7 the database Analyzer fails in the following statement:
[image]

Error:

```
Database update failed

Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

can you help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489041/mysqlerror-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Comment: seems you are right:
..... VARCHAR(333) ... works. 
but I think typo3 needs 1024 .. or?
is this an typo3 bug, or how can I solve this?

Comment: Which mysql version are you using?

Comment: mysql-server-5.7

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i found the solution.

```
 drop index lookup_string on sys_refindex;
```

then you can run database analyzer in to steps:

1. ALTER TABLE ....
2. CREATE INDEX ....
   but this is done by database analyzer in upgrade wizard